# Django force Python3

Tags: django

I have a view in Django that i've written & it works only in Python3 as the library I am using isn't available in Python2.

In the terminal, I can run the same script python3 scriptname.py and it works, whereas python scriptname.py does not.

so when I run the app, the view fails, because it's trying to run it in Python2.

How do I force Django to try and run it in Python3?

Comment: This is a matter of defining what exec "python" is pointing to

Comment: You should create your virtual environment using/with python3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In simple terms 'You Can't'. `python`/`python3` is just an executable(located somewhere in your filesystem), you can access it just by typing `python`/`python3` because the location of the executable has been added to `PATH` variable of your system. So of course `python` and `python3` points to different executable and `django` has nothing to do with it. If you must use python to run python3 you can add an alias in your `.bashrc`

```
alias python="python3"
```

with the side effect that all `python cmds..` would now be interpreted as `python3 cmds..`
on other hand you can create a custom alias to run `django` app with `python3`

```
alias dserve="python3 manage.py runserver"
```